# Multiprocessing using BlockingQueue with Android & OpenCV

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance, opencv

I am trying to increase my frame rate using with Opencv for Android. While I get the process to run I do not notice any change in my frame rate. I am wondering if there is something wrong with my logic. Also after running for about 30 seconds it falls over with a buffer error.

What I have attempted to do was to use the main thread for the I/O display of the video and a second thread for object detection.

My main activity is the producer with "implements CvCameraViewListener2" this will put each frame on blocking queue IN and take them off Blocking Queue OUT .

I then have a Consumer runnable with the processing logic. This take them off the IN Blocking queue processes them and then puts them on the OUT queue.

```
public final class CameraActivity extends FragmentActivity
    implements CvCameraViewListener2 {
  Consumer consumer1 ;
    private BlockingQueue<Mat> inFrames = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Mat>(11);
private BlockingQueue<Mat> outFrames = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Mat>(11);

  @Override
  public void onCameraViewStarted(final int width,
        final int height) {
    consumer1 = new Consumer(inFrames,outFrames);
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(consumer1);
    thread1.start();

  }

  @Override
  public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    consumer1.stopRunning();
    consumer2.stopRunning();
  }

  @Override
  public Mat onCameraFrame(final CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    final Mat rgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    // This is the producer of the blocking queue
    try {
        inFrames.put(inputFrame.rgba());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }

    try {
        return outFrames.take();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return rgba;
    }
```

Consumer Class

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable {
private final BlockingQueue<Mat> queueIn;
private final BlockingQueue<Mat> queueOut;
private boolean isRunning;

public Consumer(BlockingQueue qIn, BlockingQueue qOut) {
    queueIn = qIn;
    queueOut = qOut;
    isRunning = true;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (isRunning) { consume(queueIn.take()); }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
}
void consume(Mat src) {
    Mat mIntermediateMat = new Mat(src.rows(), src.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Mat dst = new Mat(src.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
    Mat mHsv = new Mat(src.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
    Mat mHsv2 = new Mat(src.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3);

    src.copyTo(dst);
    // Convert to HSV
    Imgproc.cvtColor(src, mHsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV, 3);

    // Remove all colors except the reds
    Core.inRange(mHsv, new Scalar(0, 86, 72), new Scalar(39, 255, 255), mHsv);
    Core.inRange(mHsv, new Scalar(150, 125, 100), new Scalar(180,255,255), mHsv2); 
    Core.bitwise_or(mHsv, mHsv2, mHsv);

    /// Reduce the noise so we avoid false circle detection
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mHsv, mHsv, new Size(7, 7), 2);
    // Find Circles
    Imgproc.HoughCircles(mHsv, mIntermediateMat, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2.0, 100);

    // Find the largest circle
    int maxRadious = 0;
    Point pt = new Point(0,0);
    if (mIntermediateMat.cols() > 0) {
        for (int x = 0; x < mIntermediateMat.cols(); x++)
        {
            double vCircle[] = mIntermediateMat.get(0,x);

            if (vCircle == null)
                break;

            int radius = (int)Math.round(vCircle[2]);
            if (radius > maxRadious) {
                maxRadious = radius;
                pt = new Point(Math.round(vCircle[0]), Math.round(vCircle[1]));
            }

        }

      // Draw the larest circle in Red
        int iLineThickness = 5;
        Scalar red = new Scalar(255, 0, 0);
        // draw the found circle
        Core.circle(dst, pt, maxRadious, red, iLineThickness);
        try{
            queueOut.put(dst);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}

public void stopRunning() {
    this.isRunning = false;
}
}
```

This is the error I get after about 30 seconds

```
01-16 14:20:23.358      510-586/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '428188e8 my.com/my.com.CameraActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
01-16 14:20:23.508  10788-24667/? E/Surface﹕ queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32
01-16 14:20:23.508  10788-24667/? E/NvOmxCamera﹕ Queue Buffer Failed. Skipping buffer.
01-16 14:20:23.508  10788-24667/? E/NvOmxCamera﹕ Dequeue Buffer Failed
01-16 14:20:23.578  10788-17442/? E/NvOmxCamera﹕ Already called release()
```

---

I would like to add that I m running on a Nexus 7 (2012) which is quod-core

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought but could you try making a clone of the input rgba at this line:

```
  inFrames.put(inputFrame.rgba().clone());
```

as you are adding and holding a reference to the last captured image in the queue and I think CvCamera might get upset if it can't release and reallocate the space; that might explain the crash.

In terms of speeding things up then presumably on a single CPU device you will only speed things up if you start to skip processing of the frames that you are taking off the queue.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I did change both my put to use the clone(), unfortunately it did not work. I know I was getting a similar error when I was using NativeCameraView changing this to JavaCameraView solved it. I suspect it may have something to do with the device compatibility with opencv. I edited my question to add aI was using a quad core device.

Comment: Actually openCV seems to be falling over very easily I just have to say Boooo to it and off it goes. I think I will have to get hold of a better device to test on, because I am wasting my time at the moment.